# How to find if a vector belongs to a span?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

> Given $U=Sp\{(2,5,-4,10),(1,1,1,1),(1,0,3,5),(0,2,-4,-8) \}$ find for which values of $a$ the vector $v=(a,a-6,4a-3,6a-1)$ belongs to $U$.

Am I correct that in order for $v$ to belong to $U$ then $v$ needs to be a linear combination of the spanning set. Then coefficients $b,c,d,e$ exist such that:
$$
b(2,5,-4,10)+c(1,1,1,1)+d(1,0,3,5)+e(0,2,-4,-8)=v
$$
So in order to find the $a$ I need to solve the system which can be represented by matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2&1&1&0&a\\
5&1&0&2&a-6\\
-4&1&3&-4&4a-3\\
-10&1&5&-8&6a-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: What you've written is correct. You want to find a, for which the system will have a solution. Try finding the rank of the system matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. You need not to find $b,c,d,e$ but just the values of $a$ such that $b,c,d,e$ exist. The four vectors of $U$ are linearly dependent and the associated rank is $3$ (check it).
You have to find $a$ such that the matrix with the four vectors of $U$ and $v$ has the same rank that is $3$.

Since  a submatrix of rank $3$ is
\begin{bmatrix}
5&1&0\\
-4&1&3\\
-10&1&5
\end{bmatrix}
it suffices to find $a$ such that the determinant of 
\begin{bmatrix}
2&1&1&a\\
5&1&0&a-6\\
-4&1&3&4a-3\\
-10&1&5&6a-1
\end{bmatrix}
is equal to zero.

Comment: Is my attempt good though?

Comment: The vectors that generate $U$ only have four components, not five, and aren’t linearly independent.

Comment: Yes, you are correct but you need not to find $b,c,d,e$. Just the values of $a$ suct that $b,c,d,e$ exist.

Comment: Sorry, I realize now that the  vectors of $U$ are not linearly independent. I edited mya answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sum twice the first row to the third one and twice the second row to the fourth one:
\begin{bmatrix}
2&1&1&0&a\\
5&1&0&2&a-6\\
0&3&5&-4&6a-3\\
0&3&5&-4&8a-13
\end{bmatrix}
Can you see a condition on $a$, now?

Comment: $a$ has to be $5$

Comment: @Yos Yes: otherwise the last column contributes to the rank and so the linear system has no solution.